# Долгое выполнение скрипта PHP и fastcgi_read_timeout

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ssh

Есть скрипт который может работать очень долго, более 1 часа, но из за fastcgi_read_timeout он тупо отрубается, и не может до конца выполнить работу.
Как на хостинге увеличить, или обойти fastcgi_read_timeout? Хостинг reg.ru. Есть доступ к ssh

Я нашел где ставится fastcgi_read_timeout, но у меня нет прав поменять его. Max_execution_time поменять могу, он стоит на 0, но это все равно не помогает. Выдается ошибка 500 internal server error

Сейчас стоит fastcgi_read_timeout=300

Пробовал запускать скрипт через `exec()`, nohup, > /dev/null &. он проработал максимум 40 мин, т.е. так же отрубился

Comment: А если в скрипт поставить set_time_limit(3600); не поможет?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: наверное, менять хостинг

Comment: Сделайте скрипт запускаемый из консоли. А дальше делаете скрипт который запускает его через  веб в фоновом режиме.  Ну и в случае если вам нужен какой то вывод,, то делаете страничку которая аяксом тянет данные, которые в свою очередь передает запущенный вами процесс.  Это один из вариантов.

Comment: Либо запускать через bash, либо сменить регистратора доменов на нормального хостера

Comment: @dev_null да стопудово, хостер виноват.

Comment: Перешел на vps.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Решил достаточно просто штатными средствами Laravel.

1. Такие запросы нет смысла выполнять через браузер, оформил в виде задания (Job).
2. Для выполнения задания, связанного с пакетной обработкой данных из БД, использовал [chunkById()-обработку](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results) (а такие длинные запросы чаще всего связаны именно с пакетной обработкой базы и параллельным обращением к внешним вэб-API).
3. В задании ограничил количество проходов chunk'а, что привело к вменяемому (до двух часов) времени выполнения задания. А для гарантированного завершения обработки всего пакета данных добавил генерирование задания по крону. Накладные потери времени на "пустую выборку" (когда все записи обработаны) составили 1 секунду на один запуск задания.
   Пример кода:

```php
        namespace App\Jobs;

        use ...

        class TeletekaFilesCheckFilePresentJob implements ShouldQueue
        {
            use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

            protected const
                CHUNK_COUNT = 100,
                CHUNK_MAX_RECORDS_PER_JOB = 300;

            /**
             * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
             *
             * @var int
             */
            public $timeout = 14400;

            /**
             * Execute the job.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function handle()
            {
                $start1 = microtime(true);
                $this->checkFilesFound();
                $start2 = microtime(true);
                echo sprintf("\nFull runtime = %.3f sec. (%.3f sec. - check MediaObjects, %.3f sec. - other)\n",
                     microtime(true) - $start1,
                     $start2 - $start1, microtime(true) - $start2);
            }

            protected function checkFilesFound(): void
            {
                echo "Checking the availability of files on storage.\n";
                $counter      = 0;
                $filesCorrect = 0;
                $filesCount   = DB::table('t_content_ext')
                                  ->where('files_state', TeletekaFile::FILES_STATE_NOT_CHECKED)
                                  ->count();
                TeletekaFile::where('files_state', TeletekaFile::FILES_STATE_NOT_CHECKED)
                            ->chunkById(self::CHUNK_COUNT, function ($files) use ($filesCount, &$counter, &$filesCorrect) {

                                // Обработка выборки

                                echo "\n", $counter += self::CHUNK_COUNT, ' of ', $filesCount, ' checked. ', $filesCorrect, ' files is correct.';
                                if ($counter >= self::CHUNK_MAX_RECORDS_PER_JOB) {
                                    echo "\nThe maximum number of items to process has been reached.";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Сам мучался недавно, надо писать cli  и выводить данные уже.
Я использовал исполнение команды

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.passthru.php

Повышение времени бесполезно, если скрипт неоптимизирован, это приводит к stackowerflow. Если это боевой, то службы сразу виснут. Помимо этого если скрипт монстрический нужно еще и оптимизировать, чистить переменные например.

https://habr.com/ru/post/22799/

Как вариант выдачу еще можно фрагментировать, побить данные на 10 частей и качать последовательно, но лучше все таки на питончике подобное писать.

Answer (score 0):

set_time_limit(0) в начале скрипта

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Многие хостинги не позволяют менять set_time_limit, в силу экономии ресурсов

Comment: @Dizzy221 скорее в силу защиты от дурака, ну или от дураков, судя по всему.

Answer (score 0):

set_time_limit() — Ограничение времени выполнения скрипта.

set_time_limit(0) - Если задан ноль, время выполнения неограничено. в вашем случае эту строку надо вставить в самом начале перед выполнением вашего скрипта.

При вызове set_time_limit() перезапускает счетчик с нуля. Другими словами, если тайм-аут изначально был 60 секунд, и через 30 секунд после запуска скрипта будет вызвана функция set_time_limit(60), то скрипт будет работать максимум 90 секунд.

Плюс ко всему. через 40 минут отрубается? нужно читать логи возможно у вас в коде возникает какая то ошибка и обрыв происходит по причине ошибки а не лимита.

Comment: while(true){file_put_contents('file',$i++); sleep(1);}.Это Весь код. Смотрю счетчик останавливается где то на 30000